# Get mutual followers in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get mutual (so from all users the user I have the most shared followers with (we both follow the same user) sorted by that count).  followers from my database scheme (mongoDB) with an aggregation function.

user scheme:

```
let User = new mongoose.Schema({
uid: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true
},
    followers: [String],
    following: [String]
})
```

where followers/following is an array of UID's

I've tried this:

```
let me = await User.findOne({uid: uid})
if (me) {
    console.log(me.followers)
    let mutual = await User.aggregate([
        // Match documents that contain the elements
        { "$match": { 
            "followers": { "$in": me.followers }
        }},

        // // De-normalize the array field content
        { "$unwind": "$followers" },

        // Match just the elements you want
        { "$match": { 
            "followers": { "$in": me.followers }
        }},

        // Count by the element as a key
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$name",  
            "mutual": { "$sum":  1}
        }}
    ])
    if (mutual) {
        console.log('mutual', mutual)
    }
}
```

but this doesn't give the correct count

Comment: It looks like that query will find all of the people who are also followed by the people that follow the original `uid`.  By "mutual followers", do you mean you want to find all of the people who follow `uid` who `uid` also follows?  Or are you looking for people who also follow someone that `uid` follows?

Comment: Question is incomplete. Can you define what you mean by mutual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$filter` and `$size` instead of unwinding the followers for each person.  You can also do this with an `$lookup` instead of 2 client-side queries.

The stages in the below pipeline:

- $match the user in question
- $lookup retrieves all uses that have a common follower, placing them in the `matched` array
- $unwind the matched array to consider each user separately
- $match - since the user in question would also be matched as having a matching follower, eliminate this 'self' entry
- $project eliminates all of the fields except the other person's `uid`, and for commonFollowers:

  - $filter to iterate each persons `followers` array, keeping only those entries that match the user in question
  - $size to return the number of elements left

```
[
  {"$match": {"uid": uid}},
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "User",
      "localField": "followers",
      "foreignField": "followers",
      "as": "matched"
  }},
  {"$unwind": "$matched"},
  {"$match": {"$expr": {"$ne": ["$matched.uid", "$uid"]}}},
  {"$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "uid": "$matched.uid",
      "commonFollowers": {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$matched.followers",
            "cond": {
              "$in": [
                "$$this",
                "$followers"
              ]
  }}}}}},
  {"$sort": {"commonFollowers": -1}}
])
```

Comment: You sir are a legend!